# Suppose $g : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \to M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, and $u \in U$ why does the derivative $dg_u$ extend to all of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, definition

> Suppose $g : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \to M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, and $u \in U$ why does the derivative $dg_u$ extend to all of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

This is my question, it comes after reading page 4 of *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint by Milnor*

This is the excerpt :

> "Now let us define the tangent space for an arbitrary smooth manifold $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$. Choose a parameterization $$g : U \to M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$$ of a neighbourhood $g[U]$ of $x \in M$, with $g(u) = x$. Here $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Think of $g$ as a mapping from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ so that the derivative $$dg_u : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^k$$ is defined. Then $$TM_x = dg_u[\mathbb{R}^m]$$"

So my question is if $g$ maps $U$ to $m$, $g : U \to M$ how can its derivative at the point $u$, $dg_u$ extend to all of $\mathbb{R}^m$ so that it maps *all of* $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$?

In other words if $g : U \to M$ how can $dg_u$ be defined so that $dg_u : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: The tangent space at $u$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.  So, $dg_u$ is automatically defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @Perturbative: It seems you're interpreting Milnor's claim as: "If $g:(a, b) \to \mathbf{R}$ is differentiable, then $g'$ extends to $\mathbf{R}$." While this turns out to be true, Milnor means something much more elementary: "If $g:(a, b) \to \mathbf{R}$ is differentiable and $a < u < b$, then $dg_{u}:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is multiplication by $g'(u)$." That's an immediate consequence of the definition of the derivative of a mapping.

Comment: I would recommend going back to a book like baby rudin and reminding yourself what the definition of derivative of a function is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you're confusing the domain of $dg$ with that of $dg_u$. Remember that $dg_u$ is the derivative of $g : U \to M$ *at the single point* $u \in U$; i.e. the best linear approximation to $g(\cdot) - g(u)$ near $u$. You might be more familiar with this as the Jacobian matrix of the mapping $g$. Linear maps/matrices always map between vector spaces - in this case since $U \subset \mathbb R^m, M \subset \mathbb R^k$, the derivative is a $k \times m$ matrix, or equivalently a linear map $\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^k$.

If you want to talk about the derivative $dg$ as a function of position $u$, then you really have a map $dg : U \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^k$ defined by $dg(u,v) = dg_u(v)$.

Comment: Your last line: Shouldn't that be $dg: U \to \mathbb R^{k\times m}?$

Comment: @zhw.: you can think about it either way. I guess $dg : U \to \mathbb R^{k \times m} : dg(u) = dg_u$ makes it literally a function of position alone.